# numpy: convert multiple assignments to a single one using OR

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

`taxi_modified` is a two-dimensional ndarray.

Code below works, but seems un-pythonic:

```
taxi_modified[taxi_modified[:, 5] == 2, 15] = 1
taxi_modified[taxi_modified[:, 5] == 3, 15] = 1
taxi_modified[taxi_modified[:, 5] == 5, 15] = 1
```

Need to assign 1 to col at index 15 if col at index 5 is 2, 3, **or** 5.

The below didn't work:

```
taxi_modified[taxi_modified[:, 5] == 2 | 3 | 5, 15] = 1
```

Comment: Be more specific than `didn't work`.  I can guess what's wrong, but can't run a test case right now.

Comment: Python evaluates the `2|3|5` first, producing `7`.  Then it does the `==` test.  It's not comparing the array to 2, then to 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fancy indexing with [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) (NumPy v1.13+), or [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) for older versions.

Here's a demo:

```
# example input array
A = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))

# calculate Boolean mask for rows
mask = np.isin(A[:, 1], [1, 5, 13])

# assign values, converting mask to integers
A[np.where(mask), 2] = -1

print(A)

array([[ 0,  1, -1,  3],
       [ 4,  5, -1,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, -1, 15]])
```

In one line, this can be written:

```
A[np.where(np.isin(A[:, 1], [1, 5, 13])), 2] = -1
```

Comment: not the most readable (for a total beginner like me), but does the job. Thanks! Just a note: the docs you link to recommend using `isin`)